# "Precompiling assets failed." when pushing tp Heroku

Tags: node.js, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku and even though it's working fine on my local (says whatever is in my `<Root/>`), page on Heroku is saying my placeholder text "react is broken" from `root.html.erb`.

when I first create the heroku app i had forgotten heroku/nodejs, and there was no "Precompiling assets failed." issue then but Heroku was still not displaying the right text. I then added heroku/nodejs (and made sure this is before heroku/ruby) and now I get "Precompiling assets failed." issue.

There are no error in the console, I read that meant this is probably I failed to webpack my frontend. I tried manually precompiling my assets by running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, but i just get a super long block of red errors in my terminal.

At the end of the long error block, this is what terminal shows:

```
 12673 //# sourceMappingURL=bundle.js.map
 12674 ;
 12675 (function() {
 12676   var context = this;
 12677 
 12678   (function() {
 12679     (function() {
 12680       var slice = [].slice;
==
/Users/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have `bundle.js.map` in my `.gitignore` if that helps.

Thanks in advance, tried to follow other posts that had Heroku "Precompiling assets failed." issues but they don't seems to work for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

although I couldn't read the whole error log via my terminal (becacuse it was too long), i was able to read it through heroku under "Activity". I realized that I had a problem with my uglifier, so here's the fix:

in `config/environments/production.rb` , change `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier`  to `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)`